# Change Screen resolution/orientation in Win8

Tags: java, windows

Is there a way to change the orientation of the Display with Java under Win8? Additionally I am curious if I can detect if auto-screenrotation is enabled (and toggle the settings).

Perhaps this might be only possible in C#, but I am curious if this is also possible in Java directly. If not Java directly, is there a chance with some other commands? Main interest is to do it in Java...

Comment: there are two-three posts about, but I don't rememeber the results

Comment: yeah, I searched and most of the results were related to Android :( I guess it might not be possible directly, cause all the functions I found up till now in Java are related to the current program (=sandbox) and therefore...

Comment: [maybe will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+[swing]+screen+rotation)

Comment: thx for the hint, but I guess this might not be possible with pure Java, cause that's something outside Javas capability - namely something on system-level...